# SQL distinct elements count in a group by same element

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have a problem to count distinct elements in a group by this element.

Let me explain this, I have two tables:

```
tb1
team  amount       
1     90                  
2     80                  
3     70                  
4     50                  
5     60

tb2   
team player 
5    1
1    1
3    2
1    2
2    2
1    3
3    3
4    3
5    3
2    4
```

The expected result is:

```
 player  nb_team Sum_amount nb_player
   1       2        150       3
   2       3        240       4
   3       4        270       3
   4       1        80        2
```

I'm doing this:

```
SELECT tb2.player, COUNT(DISTINCT tb1.team) as nb_team,
SUM(tb1.amount) AS sum,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tb2.player) 
FROM tb2 where tb1.team=tb2.team) AS nb_player
FROM tb1, tb2
WHERE tb1.team=tb2.team
GROUP BY tb2.player
ORDER BY tb2.player ASC;
```

The 3 first columns are correct but I can't get the right value for `nb_player`.

I have to count how many players are included by the number of teams

For example for the first line result:

player 1 is playing in 2 teams that involved 3 players in total (player #1,#2 and #3)

any idea?

Comment: maybe i wasn't clear, yes of course player #1 is playing in team #1 and #5, in team #1 you have player #1 and #2, and in team #5 you have player #1 and #3. so in total you have 3 players involved in team #1 and #5.

Comment: Last thing: *the 3 first rows are correct*, I think you mean *the 3 first columns are correct*

Comment: Oh yes sorry i was talking about the 3 first columns...my bad

Answer (score 1):

Counting teams and summing those teams amounts for a player needs a different resultset than counting players playing with given player in the same team. So I suggest using two different subqueries and then joining them on the player.

```
SELECT teams_total.player, teams_total.nb_team, teams_total.`sum`, 
       players_total.nb_players
FROM
( SELECT tb2.player, COUNT(DISTINCT tb1.team) as nb_team,
  SUM(tb1.amount) AS `sum` 
  FROM tb1 JOIN tb2 ON tb1.team=tb2.team
  GROUP BY tb2.player ) teams_total
JOIN
( SELECT tb2_1.player, COUNT(DISTINCT tb2_2.player) as nb_players
  FROM tb2 tb2_1
  JOIN tb1 ON tb2_1.team=tb1.team
  JOIN tb2 tb2_2 ON tb2_2.team=tb1.team
  GROUP BY tb2_1.player ) players_total
ON teams_total.player=players_total.player
ORDER BY teams_total.player ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT player, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT t2.team) AS nb_team, 
       SUM(amount) AS Sum_amount,       
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(player))
       FROM tb2 AS t
       WHERE INSTR(CONCAT(',',GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.team), ','),
                   CONCAT(',',t.team,',')) <> 0) AS nb_player 
FROM tb2 AS t2
INNER JOIN tb1 AS t1 ON t2.team = t1.team
GROUP BY player
```

`GROUP_CONCAT` is used in the correlated sub-query in order to get a comma separated list of all teams related to the `player` of the outer query. Using `INSTR` on this list, we can filter `tb2` rows and count the `DISTINCT` number of players of these teams.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc4e2/17)

Comment: @urbanschemes Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.